# Verb to use when the light of the sun 'falls" on your skin?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I wrote the following:

> The sun **hit** Erin's skin as she wandered through the alley. It felt
>   comfortable, like a warm blanket enveloping her entire body.

"Hit" is the only verb I could think of. But I wonder if there's a "gentler"
 verb to replace it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's really a lot of possible verbs you could use.  I've seen:

- touched
- caressed
- brushed
- "lingered on"
- warmed
- gleamed on

to name the first that come to mind.

**Edit:**
I reread the title of your question, why not "fell"?

> The sun gently **fell** on Erin's skin as she wandered through the alley.  It felt comfortable, like a warm blanket enveloping her entire body.

Comment: You're right. Thanks for your suggestions. I liked *touched* and *caressed*.

Comment: Each one links to a different metaphor theme, with different affordances and associations. Choose the metaphor and the rest of the words come easier.

Comment: If you're not going for a metaphor or further description of the effect, "reached" (along with "fell on") would also work

Comment: I second the question in this edit. Why use a word like "fell" in the question title, but "hit" in the sentence itself?

Answer (score 5):

How about shone? It can be used to refer to any lit surface or lighting source

Comment: Well, I guess I missed the obvious with my list. +1

Answer (score 1):

I like "smiled on" for this set.

Answer (score 1):

The sun **embraced** Erin's skin as she wandered through the alley. It felt comfortable, like a warm blanket enveloping her entire body

The sun **kissed** Erin's skin as she wandered through the alley...

- lit
- cosseted

Answer (score 0):

Erin **sunned** herself as she walked through the alley. It felt comfortable *on her skin*, like a warm blanket enveloping her entire body.